# Calling methods in C# like in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net-to-c#

I'm trying to migrate VB.NET to C#:

```
Public Sub customfunc()
  "my codes here"
End Sub

Public Sub main()
  Call customfunc()
End Sub
```

So i'm trying to call `customfunc()` inside `main()` but there is no call function in c#.

How do I do this in c#?

Comment: `Call` in VB.NET? That looks a bit archaic. Must have been a VB6 code originally.

Comment: Have you read language tutorials for C#? Purchased a book or otherwise consulted learning resources? This isn't much beyond a typical "hello world" first program, and we expect you to do some research *before* asking questions here.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'll post an update later if it works..

Answer (score 0):

Just do it without the `Call`:

```
customfunc();
```